# Axios Eject: How to proceed?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios

Is there a way for me to eject my interceptors when they are set in the following manner?  This is a react application and I have the following code in my index.js for all global axios calls.

In my onRefreshToken() call, I would like to somehow eject the global response interceptor to send a new request to a refresh token API.  I've seen examples of people utilizing variables or function calls, but not sure how I would implement.

**Request Interceptor**

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    config.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
```

**Response Interceptor**

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response;
  },
  error => {
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    const substring = '401';
    const errorCheck = errorMessage.includes(substring);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (errorCheck) {
        onRefreshToken({
          initialRequest: error.config,
          resolve,
          reject,
        });
      } else {
        refreshFailLogout();
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my instance of handling this requirement to work.  Although it could be improved, I followed Shinework's approach with some tweaks against the API access_token and refresh_token TTL's.  If anyone is curious how to approach this in more detail, let me know and I can add more of my approach, I was able to get it to work without ejecting the request and response interceptors. Note: this was within a React, Redux (with Thunk), and React-Router app.

I know there isn't a lot of documentation out there, so if you're struggling please ask for some help!
The key function to get it to work:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('Response Success', response);
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(error.response);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (
        error.response.status === 401
        && error.config.headers.Authorization === 'Bearer undefined'
      ) {
        refreshFailLogout();
        reject(error);
      } else if (error.response.status === 401) {
        onRefreshToken({
          initialRequest: error.config,
          resolve,
          reject,
        });
      } else {
        refreshFailLogout();
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  },
);
```

House your redux dispatch, action calls within the saveTokens and refreshFailLogout.  This works with use cases for even smaller TTLs